# Botón elimiar php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

estoy realizando un CRUD con PHP, y me gustaría que al darle al botón "Eliminar", borrase de la base de datos el producto seleccionado.
He conseguido que coja el id del producto dependiendo a que producto hagas click, pero estoy bloqueado con el resto, soy principiante en PHP.

Este es el código php:

```
    <?php
require "../class/Cesta.php";

session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION["recetas"])) {
    $_SESSION["recetas"]    = (new Receta())->getRecetas();
}

$nueva_sesion_recetas=$_SESSION["recetas"];
for ($i=0; $i < count($nueva_sesion_recetas) ; $i++) { 
    if (isset($_POST["ver"][$i])) {
        $unareceta = new Receta();
        $unareceta->setId($nueva_sesion_recetas[$i]->id_receta);
        $_SESSION["recetaIndividual"]= $unareceta->id_receta;
        var_dump($_SESSION["recetaIndividual"]);
        
    }

}
```

Y estos son los botones en los que recoge el id del producto:

```
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="POST">
            <?php
            echo "<table class='table table-striped table-light'>";
            foreach ($_SESSION["recetas"] as $key => $receta) {
                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>{$receta->getNombre()}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$receta->getTiempo()}</td>";
                echo "<td><button href='./mostrar-receta.php' class='btn btn-success float-right'type='submit' name='ver[$key]' value='{$receta->getId()}'>Ver</button></td>";
                echo "<td><button href='' class='btn btn-warning float-right' name='modificar[$key]' value='{$receta->getId()}'>Modificar</button></td>";
                echo "<td><button class='btn btn-danger float-right' name='eliminar[$key]' value='{$receta->getId()}'>Eliminar</button></td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            ?>
        </form>
```

Gracias por vuestro timepo.

Comment: *"He conseguido que coja el id del producto dependiendo a que producto hagas click, pero estoy bloqueado con el resto, soy principiante en PHP."* En el bloque donde ocurre eso, debes programar código para hacer la eliminación en la base de datos. ¿Cuál es el *bloqueo* en ese sentido? ¿Que no sabes conectar a la base de datos? ¿Con qué API piensas conectar? ¿Qué no sabes escribir consultas del tipo `DELETE`? ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto?

Comment: No se hacer la consulta DELETE  en base a ese id que coge.

Comment: [Revisa el tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx). Tienes que escribir una consulta del tipo `DELETE FROM elNombreDeLaTabla WHERE laColumna=elValorRecogidoDelFormulario`, pero ten en cuenta que desde PHP debes usar una API (PDO, mysqli) para interactuar con la base de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me revisare ese tutorial a ver si me ayuda a realizarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obtienes el id del producto y lo guardas en una variable, en mi caso id_producto, luego le das en value del boton eliminar, el valor de este id ,su nombre y su id

```
name="btn_delete" id="btn_delete" value="<?php echo $id_producto; ?>"
```

hasta ahi vamos bien, luego en el php que llamamos al boton cuando se presione(eliminar.php o donde lo tengas), le creamos una consulta, primero obteniendo el valor del btn_delete y guardandolo en una variable, seguido de la consulta de eliminar

```
$var=$_POST['btn_delete'];

$sql="DELETE FROM tabladeldato WHERE iddelproducto ='$var'";
?>
```

luego de eso ya quedaria eliminado el registro

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso solucionó mi problema !!